# Set time between NSTimer selector calls

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is my code

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 
                                     target:self 
                                     selector:@selector(t:) 
                                     userInfo:endtime 
                                     repeats:YES ];

-(void)t:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if ([timer.userInfo timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
        [timer invalidate];

}
```

Is it possible to set the time between calls to t method, because the default is too fast for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the time between calls to t method, because the
>   default is too fast for me?

Right now you're passing 0 for the interval. Use a larger value for a longer interval:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 
                                     target:self 
                                     selector:@selector(t:) 
                                     userInfo:endtime 
                                     repeats:YES ];
```

This schedules the timer to fire every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the time interval (in seconds) inbetween the calls (see [NSTimer doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)), where you did set `0`. So you can for example set `0.5` for "once ever half second" or `1 / 30.0` for "30 times a second". Note that `NSTimer` calls are not absolutely exact and you may have to calculate the exact time since last call if you need accuracy (e.g. animations).

Comment: I would do animations on a separate thread as they are CPU intensive.